# How to get Users List on button click instead of directly?

Tags: angularjs, playframework, coffeescript

I am trying to develop one application template from Google search in my local system-[using](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/modern-web-template) or [git](https://github.com/lashford/modern-web-template), here we are displaying the Users list normally, but how can I get/list the same users list on button click instead of getting directly displaying on UI. Is there any configuration is required to integrate with service/controller with html form button ? Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: display your code here

Comment: @Zubairsadiq, I am using the same code from git or the given url.

Comment: Initially, when you load page make the list empty. Then write a ng-click function on button, in that function write your code to get the list.